# Store the template that the class was initialized with

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to figure out how to store my template, ill write a example:

```
class cDebugInfo
{
private:
    DWORD * address;
    string name;
    template Type;

public:
    Type GetFormattedValue()
    {
        return *(Type*)address;
    }
    cDebugInfo(){}
    template <class T>
    cDebugInfo(DWORD Address, string Name){
        address = Address;
        name = Name;
        Type = T;
    }
};
```

My goal, is to be able to add a item to my array:

```
std::vector<cDebugInfo>DebugItems;

template <class T>
void AddItem(std::string name, DWORD Address)
{
    DebugItems.push_back(cDebugInfo(Address, name));
}
cDebugInfo* GetItemByNameP(std::string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DebugItems.size(); i++)
    {
        if (DebugItems[i].name == name)
        {
            return &DebugItems[i];
        }
    }
}
```

So i add the items to my array like this:

```
AddItem<int>(0x1337, "Test");
AddItem<string>(0x1337, "Test2");
```

And Therefore being able to call:

```
GetItemByName("Test")->GetFormattedValue();
```

And that should return the value in INT read form the given address since the template passed when i add the item, is a int. And ofcourse, the following should return the value stored in the address pointed by my pointer as a string:

```
GetItemByName("Test2")->GetFormattedValue();
```

I need it to "remember" what template was passed on to the class.
NOTE: Everything else works fine when i use GetItemByName with a template, but the thing is i dont know what template it is when i get them, only when i add them.
Thank you.

Comment: how about `GetItemByName("Test")->GetFormattedValue<int>();`?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to _store_ the type information; the hard part is how to _extract_ it. At the call site of your `GetFormattedValue` you need to know statically what the return type is (unless you want to return a discriminated union like Boost.any). Weirdly though, a _formatted_ value usually means a string - are you sure you don't just want to control the formatting and get a string back?

Comment: @ixSci Yes, if i also use a template, as i stated above, it works. But i need to retrieve the value without knowing if its a int, or bool or whatever.

Comment: @Useless i guess i could use a enum with different types and a switch, but i wanted to make it 100% dynamic :P

Comment: You can search about "type erasure" in C++ and take a look at [boost.any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: 100% dynamic is not possible in C++. What you want is not achievable in C++. Your best bet is something like `boost.any`, `boost.typeerasure` like it was already said. Nothing better could be done since C++ doesn't support such degree of a dynamism.

Comment: If you don't know the return type of GetFormattedValue() you'll have a hard time doing anything with it unless the caller is also a templatized context (class or whatever). Which is perhaps where you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible because every expression in C++ must have a known type at compile time. Consider this:

```
auto value = GetItemByName("BestItem")->GetFormattedValue();
```

`GetItemByName(...)` gives me a `cDebugInfo*`, but what does `GetFormattedValue()` give me? This must be the same type for every `cDebugInfo*` so that the above expression can be valid, so the type cannot withheld until runtime. So the general solution is impossible.

However, you can add specific solutions based on what it is you want to do. Let's say we just want to be able to print the formatted value. We can do that:

```
class cDebugInfo {
    std::function<void()> printer; // type-erased functor
    ...
public:
    template <class T>
    cDebugInfo(DWORD Address, string Name){
        address = Address;
        name = Name;
        printer = [this]{
            std::cout << "Value as " << typeid(T).name() << ": "
                      << *reinterpret_cast<T*>(address) << '\n';
        };
    }
};
```

This approach is called "type erasure". In this case, the lambda "stores" the type `T`, but the class itself just needs to know that it's a nullary function that returns `void`. We can expose that via:

```
void printValue() { printer(); }
```

So that:

```
GetItemByValue("BestItem")->printValue();
```

will print the value correctly based on the type it was constructed with.

Comment: Wow, thanks, my aim was to store it in a string and print it in my log, and this is exactly what i wanted :D

Comment: You can store text easier than that.